# Perl regex to capture text between two anchor words but ignore anchor word in comments

Tags: regex, perl, verilog

I like to capture the text in a say a verilog file from a word 'module' to the word 'endmodule' . The verilog file may contain multiple modules, so i like to pin point a specific one.

Also i want to ignore any 'endmodule' word in any comment block.

Verilog file sample:

```
module whatever
//endmodule
// endmodule
// asadsadadsa endmodule
// enasaa endmodule asas
/* endmodule */
endmodule // whatever
module nonsense
//
// bla bla
//
endmodule // nonsense
```

Say i want to capture the module **whatever** from above. I am using Perl single line mode.

So far i got to this point:

```
if ($content =~ m/(module\s+whatever[\s(#]?.*?endmodule(?:\s*\/\/\s*whatever)?)/s)
{
    print $1;
}
else
{
    print "NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!!!!\n";
}
```

So far, this has matched to the first occurrence of '**//endmodule**'

Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: A simple tokenizer/parser would be much simpler for this. Regexes are fun and cool, but they are not the solution to every single parsing question. I don't recommend them here.

Comment: Verilog is not easy to lex or parse. Use verilog-perl unless the source is highly constrained, like a netlist or code that follows strict coding guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the entire file into one regex, read one line at a time.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my ($file,$module) = qw(verilog.v whatever);

open(VERILOG_FILE, $file) or die "cannot read $!";
my $start=0;
my $store = "";
foreach my $line (<VERILOG_FILE>) {
    die "nested module inside module:'${module}'" if $start && $line =~ m/^\s*module\W/;
    $start|= $line =~ m/^\s*module ${module}\W/;
    $store.=$line if $start;
    if ($start and $line =~ m/^\s*endmodule/) {
        print $store;
        exit 0;
    }
}
die "cannot file module '$module' in file '$file'" if ($start==0);
die "missing endmodule for '$module'"
```

With the given Verilog file sample from the question and assuming the name is verilog.v, then output will be:

```
module whatever
//endmodule
// endmodule
// asadsadadsa endmodule
// enasaa endmodule asas
/* endmodule */
endmodule // whatever
```

Answer (score 3):

This one is a bit tricky. The idea is usually to distinguish all the possible things that you do want to match, put them in an alternation and repeat.

So what do we want to match?

- a single-line comment: `//` to the end of the string, no matter what.
- a block-comment: `/*` until the next `*/`, no matter what.
- anything else, as long as it doesn't start `endmodule`

The last part can be accomplished by using a negative lookahead at every position in the repetition.

So let's put that together:

```
$content =~ m~
  module\s+whatever      # marks the start of the module
  (?:                    # each instance of this alternation matches one kind of
                         # module "token"
    //.*+                # match a single-line comment
  |                      # or
    /[*]                 # open a block comment
    (?:(?![*]/)[\s\S])*+ # match anything as long as it doesn't close the comment
    [*]/                 # close the block comment
  |                      # or
    (?!endmodule)[\s\S]  # match anything as long as it doesn't close the module
  )*+                    # repeat
  endmodule
  ~x
```

The trick is that the first two alternatives skip you past the comments, so that you are only paying attention to `endmodule` outside of them.

The `*+` are [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). They are (for the most part) an optimization, but the one after the `//` and the one around the alternation are strictly necessary (otherwise backtracking might give you false positives).

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/aDcQMj)

However, since you are dealing with a standardized file format, you might be better off looking for a parser of that kind of file.